Convert list to dictionary nodejs express application generator api
This is post API
router.post('/', async function(req, res, next) {
    const subscribersFile= path.join(__dirname, "../subscribers.json")
    const data = await fs.readFile(subscribersFile, "utf-8")
    let subscribers= JSON.parse(data)

    let subscriber = req.body
 
    const id = uuid.v4();
    subscriber = {...subscriber, id: id}

    subscribers = [...subscribers, subscriber]
    const json = JSON.stringify(subscribers)
    await fs.writeFile(subscribersFile, json, "utf-8")

    return res.json({data: "POST", body: req.body})
});

This code works but review comments suggested to change it to dictionary.
How to change subscribers = [...subscribers, subscriber] to a dictionary?

The below code uses a Map object.
const uuid = require('uuid');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

//NOTE: for testing, the file path changed to this project folder
const subscribersFile = path.join(__dirname, './subscribers.json');

let subscribers;
try {
  //NOTE: for code brevity, a synchronous function used instead of an async
  const data = fs.readFileSync(subscribersFile, 'utf-8');
  // deserialising the Map object
  subscribers = new Map(JSON.parse(data));
} catch (error) {
  subscribers = new Map([]);
}

//NOTE: for testing, a hard coded value used instead of req.body
const newsubscriber = {
  name: 'A',
};
const id = uuid.v4();

//adding the new subscriber to the existing lists
subscribers.set(id, newsubscriber.name);

// serializing the Map object
const json = JSON.stringify(Array.from(subscribers.entries()));
fs.writeFileSync(subscribersFile, json, 'utf-8');

Test results
Note : The below output resulted in the output file when running the
same code 4 times. Therefore only the uuid has been changed. The subscriber
name remains the same. In the production code, it will produce the desired results.
[["044567fe-7407-4972-859d-6c78e88b033a","A"],
["d46cab22-2d0c-4ae9-834d-c60dcff0d743","A"],
["d655a085-9e3c-4681-888e-324546eb19ef","A"],
["c0532239-35af-48fe-b4b6-b0486c477080","A"],

Citation
How to serialize a Map in javascript?

Thank you for your confirmation. I humbly request  you to keep rating content in this forum - upvote or downvote - both are equally acceptable. Rating will make the content rightly usable to everyone. By the way, in case of any clarifications you may require in the code, please comment, shall respond.
